# SQL Server Pivot-table with Numeric Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

When I run a simple query, where AskiaID is a numeric field, in MS SQL Server Management Studio, I get this :-

```
SELECT TaskResult, [80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443] FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Call] as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(TaskResult)
   FOR RTRIM(CAST(AgentID AS CHAR)) IN ([80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443])
) AS PivotResult
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

If I change the query to its original form :-

```
SELECT TaskResult, [80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443] FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Call] as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(TaskResult)
   FOR AgentID IN (80444, 80421, 80438, 80435, 80046, 80427, 80378, 80442, 80419, 80436, 80379, 80410, 80439, 80437, 80405, 80377, 80383, 80406, 80420, 80443)
) AS PivotResult
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '80444'.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use a subquery to fix the column.

Comment: Care to expand on your idea please Gordon?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is casting to char but not specifying the length. This is very problematic...but in this case you got lucky. This post discusses why it is bad with varchar but the same logic applies to char. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length Of course, since you have varying lengths of data you should probably be using varchar anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @Statistic_Call table
(
    AgentId int,
    TaskResult varchar(10)
)
insert into @Statistic_Call(AgentId, TaskResult)
values
(80444, 'Test 1'),
(80444, 'Test 2'),
(80421, 'Test 1'),
(80438, 'Test 2'),
(80435, 'Test 1'),
(80046, 'Test 1'),
(80427, 'Test 3'),
(80378, 'Test 1'),
(80442, 'Test 1'),
(80419, 'Test 4'),
(80436, 'Test 1'),
(80379, 'Test 2'),
(80410, 'Test 1'),
(80439, 'Test 1'),
(80437, 'Test 3'),
(80405, 'Test 1'),
(80377, 'Test 2'),
(80383, 'Test 1'),
(80406, 'Test 1'),
(80420, 'Test 3'),
(80443 ,'Test 1');


SELECT TaskResult, [80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443] 
FROM 
(
select TaskResult, AgentId, 1 as rownum --row_number() over (order by(select null)) as rownum
from @Statistic_Call as PivotData
) as src
PIVOT
(
   count(rownum)
   FOR AgentId IN ([80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443])
) AS PivotResult;
```

Comment: <pre>`DECLARE @Columns as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL as VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns=COALESCE(@Columns+',','')+QUOTENAME(AgentID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT AgentID FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Agent] where TaskID=1937) AS B
ORDER BY AgentID

SET @SQL='SELECT TaskResult,'+@Columns+'
FROM (SELECT TaskResult,AgentID,1 AS rownum FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Agent] where TaskID=1937) as PivotData
PIVOT (COUNT(rownum) FOR AgentID IN ('+@Columns+')) AS PivotResult'
PRINT @SQL

EXEC(@SQL)`</pre>

Comment: nice!!! there is no actual need for a derived rownum column, you could use a non nullable column eg. TaskID  .... `' FROM (SELECT TaskResult,AgentID, Taskid FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Agent] where TaskID=1937) as PivotData PIVOT (COUNT(Taskid) FOR AgentID....`

Comment: Yes, you could avoid the use of the rownum column. I may develop this code further, for example, to perform more advanced calculations than just counting. Sums of costs or hours, say, so the rownum column is useful. Thanks for your help btw :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using strings but not casting?

```sql
SELECT TaskResult, [80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443] FROM [RSM.Statistics].[dbo].[Statistic_Call] as PivotData
PIVOT
(
   COUNT(TaskResult)
   FOR AgentID IN ([80444], [80421], [80438], [80435], [80046], [80427], [80378], [80442], [80419], [80436], [80379], [80410], [80439], [80437], [80405], [80377], [80383], [80406], [80420], [80443])
) AS PivotResult
```

Comment: the query will raise error: `Invalid column name 'TaskResult'.` because TaskResult is in the aggregation.